# changing global RAM of docker in linux

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set default RAM for containers on redhat linux, how we can change the global configuration in Redhat linux ?

As shown in the screenshot below we can adjust the RAM on docker desktop easily. How we can do it in linux using command line.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to (and you can't, really).

That setting is only for the Linux VM that Docker Desktop needs to run on Mac and Windows.

There is no such VM layer when running Docker on Linux. You can adjust each container's memory limits with the same switches you'd use on Docker on Mac or Windows.